# How to run codeigniter inside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I am trying to run codeigniter project inside wordpress project. But it seems to be codeigniter controller acting like wordpress functionality

Comment: Exclude codeigniter folder by mention it in .htaccess in root directory. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295366/exclude-a-folder-directory-from-rewriterule

Comment: Thanks for reply .but that doesn't work for me

Comment: Post your efforts and try to add more detail in your question.