# .htaccess redirect for wordpress permalinks excluding uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed the permalink structure for a wordpress site from

```
Day and name    http://www.domain.com/2016/12/17/sample-post/
```

to

```
Post name   http://www.domain.com/sample-post/
```

using the following htaccess rewrites, which do work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/$2
```

however the problem now, is that its rewriting image URLs as well, example:

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Lego-2.jpg
```

is now redirecting to

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/Lego-2.jpg
```

which is breaking images.  How can I exclude wp-content/uploads from the RedirectMatch htaccess rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude a folder/directory from RewriteRule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295366/exclude-a-folder-directory-from-rewriterule)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make that change in settings > permalinks without writing your own htaccess provide htaccess is writable just add `/%postname%` to the end of custom in permalinks setting and it will not break image or style links