# Moving WordPress from subdomain to main domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, cpanel

I’ve read the WordPress Codex instructions regarding moving WordPress, but none of the information provided seems to apply to my exact situation and I have a couple of questions before I go and break things.
I have a main domain on which my old wordpress site is currently running (e.g - example.com)  I wanted to change the layout of the website but at the same time wanted to keep my main site running so made a subdomain (beta.example.com) and created my new wordpress website on this.
Now I want to make my beta website the main website (i.e make beta.example as example.com) and remove the main website, how do I go about that?
I am using cpanel and both my folders are in the public html directory
Thanks in advance.

Comment: point example.com to main website folder and redirect the beta.example.com trafiic to example.com

Comment: I covered this in an answer to a similar question, also using cPanel, also with the folder in the public_html folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477620/changing-wordpress-site-url-from-subdomain-to-sub-directory/41478969#41478969

Comment: @user3040610 the thing you're not considering is that the URLs will be stored in the databases, so you'll likely get 500 errors when accessing either site

Comment: @Daniel Thank you, Just a small doubt thou wrt to your ans in step 4 you mentioned  "Perform a "Find and Replace" in the database, find all instances of your current url "example.myrooturl.com" and replace it with the new url "myrooturl.com/example" - so I have to change my beta.example.com to example.com and in step 6 instead of creating a new folder  I have to replace the content of example.com with the content of beta.example.com?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes, replace beta.example.com with example.com or www.example.com. For the second answer, move from the subfolder to the main directory, as a precaution I would also rename your .htaccess file to "htaccess.old" then, wen logged into the admin, go to permalinks and click "save" - your old settings should still be there

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the help and your prompt reply, it worked and all is fine!

Comment: That's great, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Backup: Always backup the files / database of the site(s) you choose to work with

Step 2: Move files: Delete the contents of example.com's document root and move the contents of blog.example.com to example.com

Step3: Change home/site-url: The daabase mght have other hard coded urls too. So changing the home / site url alone will not be enough and a full database search-replace is needed.

I would not recommend using notepad++ or any text editor to change the website url as it has a great chance to break the layout of the website and I have seen it may times happen. I always use and recommend you to use the `Database Search and Replace Script` from [here](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Download the version 2.1.0 to the document root of the website as search.php

Now call the script via your browser (as domain.com/search.php). The script autopopulates the database details. The rest of the instructions there are self explanatory to follow.

Step 4: Finishing up: Check the `.htaccess` file that there are no redirects to the blog.example or similar redirects. If yes, remove them and replace with the default .htaccess wordpress rules.

That should do it.

Comment: please check my question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364863/moving-wordpress-child-webitemultisite-schild-to-new-server

Answer (score 0):

Steps are below:-

1. Make a new folder into your root in Cpanel and move your old domain(example.com) files to the new folder as a backup
2. Move your subdomain (beta.example.com)folder's files into root in cpanel
3. rename your ht access file it will automatically created when your WordPress run into the browser.
4. Into your PHPMyAdmin create new database (like new_database)
5. Download your subdomain database and open it into editor something (like notpad++)
6. Into notpad++ press crt+f, from tabs click to replace, into find section put beta.example.com and into replace with section put example.com then save it make sure you do not use HTTP, https or www when performing the replacing task.
7. Now goto your WordPress directory wp-config file and change your database name with newly created one username and password too.
8. Visit example.com/wp-admin login there with your login details you were using to login into beta.example.com/wp-admin.
9. Into deshboard->setting click to permalinks and select %%postname%%

Thanks, I hopes it will work for you as example.com

Comment: please check my question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364863/moving-wordpress-child-webitemultisite-schild-to-new-server