# WordPress Permalinks not found in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, subdirectory

I have WordPress installed in the root folder and in a subfolder. I can access the home page for the WordPress site in the subdomain, but the permalinks does not work – error 404. I have tried to reset the permalinks, but it did not help. I can’t find any .htaccess file, so I have created one myself and placed it in the subfolder directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /projects/bigsargefitness/  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /projects/bigsargefitness/index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Here is a link to the subfolder WordPress site:
http://ninahortendesigns.com/projects/bigsargefitness/

I have set the database options to the above direction.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove the `RewriteBase` file in the root website's  `.htaccess` file. Also, is `/projects/` in the root of the drive ? or is it something more like `/home/username/www/projects/`

Comment: I tried to remove the RewriteBase file in the root .htaccess, but it didn’t work. I have the WP site in the root, then projects are under the root folder (along with wp-amin folder etc.) The subfolder for the WP site are under projects folder
ninahortendesigns/projects/bigsargefitness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to look at a few things:

1. .htaccess file in the root WP site (WP1) and edit it so that WP1 doesn't catch the URLs and generate 404 errors, I'm not sure if that comment assisted, I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295366/exclude-a-folder-directory-from-rewriterule) answer for a similar issue.
2. .htaccess file in the sub WP site (WP2) and rename it to "htaccess.old" then log into your wp2/wp-admin, go to "Settings->Permalinks" check the URL structure is as desired (it doesn't usually change) and click "Save" at the bottom of the page. This will regenerate your .htaccess file within the context of the sub-directory and you shouldn't get 404 errors when you visit sub-pages like [this](http://ninahortendesigns.com/projects/bigsargefitness/classes/)

Here's the code from the first link edited so that it should work with your site, although if you have additional rules, you should only insert the line under the comment.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# Include in the next line all folders to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(projects) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

If you have custom rules, only insert these lines

```
# Include in the next line all folders to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(projects) [NC]
```

Assuming you're a designer and are uploading examples of sites you've built, you should only have to do step 2 the next time you upload a new site to the wp1/projects/ sub-directory

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the right direction. I have updated the .htaccess file as you suggested in the root folder and named the .htaccess file in the subfolder to .htaccess.old
I saved the permalinks, but I still get 404 not found error. I also checked the wp-config to make sure the define(‘RELOCATE’,true) is not there. I use godaddy as host.

Comment: Why don't you change your permalink structure to "Plain" as a test and see if the 404 pops up again. If it doesn't then we can assume the issue is the htaccess in the sub-folder, if it does, then the error may still lie in the root htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The permalinks works when I am using plain option. 
This is how my subfolder .htaccess file looks like:
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress

Do you have any suggestions of how I can get it to work with post name setting? Otherwise, the plain option will work perfectly to showcase the project. Thank you so much for the help. You saved my day.

Comment: @Nina I'm pleased to see it works on the plain setting. Can you re-enable your old setting and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I tried to set it to post name again, but I get the 404 error. Plain works great.

Comment: Well I guess the URL won't matter much since it's not for SEO nor do you need people to remember them!

Comment: Yes, I am thinking the same thing. It's only for showcase, so it should work fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

### Cause

Error 404 occurs when the resource or path you requested cannot be reached. In this case it's likely because URL rewrite isn't working properly, hence the permalink requests were still being directed to the requested path (e.g. /projects/bigsargefitness/your-category/your-post-name) instead of the rewritten path (i.e. /projects/bigsargefitness/index.php).

The following solution assumes you use Debian/Ubuntu, otherwise the principles should remain the same.

### Solution

1. Firstly, ensure that the rewrite engine has been installed:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   ```
2. Then, ensure that the engine is allowed for the subdirectory by editing/adding the following lines in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site.conf`:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/projects/bigsargefitness/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

   **The key here is to ensure that the line says `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride None`.**
3. Finally, restart your server:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Let me know if this helps.