# Rewrite all requests for subfolder to index.php in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a script which lives next to a WordPress instance in a subfolder.

All requests of the type `domain.com/special_folder/whatever` shall trigger a fallback to the index.php in `special_folder` which worked fine by using the following `.htaccess` in the subfolder:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Now I am on the server where WordPress also has its own `.htaccess`. I thought my subfolders `.htaccess` would simply override the one from WP but that´s not case. Furthermore I already tried [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26352372/4383432) but it just made all the pages of WP not reachable but nothing more.

How can I sneak past the WP `.htaccess` and get my subfolder `.htaccess` do its job again?

**Edit:** Using different htaccess for Fallback, updated code

Comment: So what happens when you enter `domain.com/special_folder/whatever` in browser?

Comment: I am thrown back into my WP instance and see the 404 page there.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `/special_folder/.htaccess`, have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`RewriteEngine On` is needed to override rewrite rule of parent folder.

Comment: Didn´t change anything it seems. Sorry.

Comment: That is strange because I have tested this exact rule on my WP installation by creating a new folder with just `index.php` in it and it worked quite well.