# Wordpress blogpost subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a blog subdirectory

`public_html/blog`

the site can be accessed like this

`https://example.com/blog`

by default, the blogposts are accessed like this

`https://example.com/blog/index.php/hello-world`

I want to remove the index.php and access the posts like this

`https://example.com/blog/hello-world`

I have this .htaccess file from where i looked into how to install a wordpress subdirectory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

> https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-step-by-step/

However when I tried to change it via

> Settings -> Permalinks -> Common Settings -> Post name

I end up with a 404 from the main wordpress installation. I have a faint idea that this might be an issue with the htaccess? But i don't really get how to fix it.

Comment: check with debugger what the reason of 404 error. for doing so
in wp-config file change debug value to true

Comment: I think index.php shouldn't place into permalink?
It's a very easy thing there are no complex settings. If you have time you contact me.

Comment: @PHPGeek i turned it on and it still redirects to the 404 of the main wordpress installation

Comment: @MonzurAlam index.php only appears when i open a post. I know it's an easy setting. The problem is when I remove the index.php with the settings it gets redirected to the 404 of the main wordpress installation.

Comment: can you share your login credential for debug issue?

Comment: @MonzurAlam that will probably not be possible because this is an agency work, for security purposes.

Comment: can you clone your site into another directory & create a new user for me? @SiG

Answer (score 0):

> when I remove the index.php with the settings it gets redirected to the 404 of the main wordpress installation

That's because the rewriting for that main WordPress installation rewrites everything that does not match a physically existing file or folder, to its own `index.php`. (Which then goes and looks up the requested URL in its database, doesn't find any matching content, and responds with a 404.)

`/blog/index.php/hello-world` matches the existing `index.php` in that folder (the rest is considered PATH_INFO), so the rewriting of the main WP leaves it alone.

But `/blog/hello-world` does not match anything that exists in the file system.

So you need to exclude any paths starting with `/blog/` from the rewriting inside your *main* WP installation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297697/1427878 shows the basic way to do that, although there the content between the `# BEGIN WordPress`/ `# END WordPress` comments gets modified (which one should not do, because that part will be overwritten when the permalink settings get flushed in the backend.)

Better to do it outside of those. Try and put this at the very top of your .htaccess of the main WP installation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/ - [L]
```

For any path that starts with `/blog/` (leading slash has already been removed from the relative path that RewriteRule matches against), simply do no rewriting at all, and make this the last rule to be processed at the same time.

Comment: i am still getting a 404... am i supposed to add it before or after `#BEGIN WordPress` ?

Comment: No, _outside_ of these comments.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am still getting a 404.

Comment: Is that still a 404 from the _main_ WordPress? Or is it maybe from the one inside the blog folder now?

Comment: Its from the main wordpress

Comment: comment section doesnt seem to format properly but this is how my my main htaccess looks like `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/ - [L]

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress`

Comment: I can't see what would go wrong with that. You can try and replace the `L` flag with `END`, that really stops all rewrite processing for the current request in that place, but it should not really make a difference.

Comment: Do you think this might need some kind of server rule? I remember watching in kinsta about wordpress multisite that a subdirectory about some kind of server rule. But since these are two separate wordpress installation instead of multisite i didnt think itd be relevant.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "server rule".

Comment: on this page (https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-multisite/) it says  ***If your site is hosted on Kinsta, you won’t need to configure the .htaccess rules because our hosting stack does not utilize the Apache web server. However, if you are looking to set up a subdirectory subsite, you’ll need to reach out to our support team to edit the Nginx configuration.***

Comment: And that is where you are hosting this? Then you should probably contact their support team, as it says there. And if not, then I don't see how this would be relevant?

Comment: It is hosted in kinsta yes, but this article is for wordpress multisite installations. Mine is just running on two regular wordpress installations.

Comment: But that changes little about their specific setup. If they are not using Apache but Nginx, then you probably won't get too far by trying to solve this problem with Apache configuration files.